# PostgreSQL creating trigger which blocks the too much updated rows

Tags: postgresql, triggers, database-trigger

I would like to create a trigger procedure, which disable the update transaction when someone want to modify more then 5 records on a table.
I am trying with this code, but not works.

```
create FUNCTION tr_test1_trx() RETURNS trigger AS $tr_test1_trx$declare
counter_ integer := 0;
begin
raise notice 'trigger fired';
select COUNT(*) into counter_ from att_test.tr_test1 where object_name = new.object_name;
if counter_>5 then 
RAISE EXCEPTION 'ERROR: CANNOT UPDATE MORE THAN 5';
END IF;
END;
$tr_test1_trx$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_test1_trx BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON att_test.tr_test1
FOR EACH row EXECUTE PROCEDURE tr_test1_trx();
```

Comment: Do you mean update more than one row with **one** statement?

Comment: yes, in one statement, its allowed to update only 5 rows max...

Answer (score 0):

You need a statement level trigger, not a row level trigger for that.

```
create or replace function block_mass_changes()
  returns trigger
as
$$
declare
  l_numrows integer;
begin
  select count(*)
    into l_numrows
  from new_rows;
  raise notice 'Rows: %', l_numrows;
  if l_numrows > 5 then
    raise 'Updating or inserting more than 5 rows is not allowed';
  end if;
  return null;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Then you need to create one trigger for UPDATE and one for INSERT because it's not possible to define a statement level trigger for two actions:

```
CREATE TRIGGER block_updates_trigger
    AFTER UPDATE ON att_test.tr_test1
    REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_rows
    FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION block_mass_changes();

CREATE TRIGGER block_inserts_trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON att_test.tr_test1
    REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS new_rows
    FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION block_mass_changes();
```

Comment: do you have any idea to make this solution without 'REFERENCING' command?... because I am using older Postgre version which doesn't support it.

Comment: you should have mentioned that you are using an old Postgres version. 9.6 or 9.5 are somewhat dated anyway, so maybe it's a good reason to plan an upgrade to a modern version. I can't think of a solution using row level triggers though.